# ImageMagick's composite on HSL (not HSB nor HSV)

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, color-space, hsl, hsb

Just I want to do is to replace Photoshop's HSL-based blend modes (color/hue/saturation/luminosity) by writing a CUI tool.
Better if I can do it via RMagick.

ImageMagick can manage HSL colorspace, but ImageMagick's composite operators Colorize/Hue/Saturation/Luminize are hard-coded to be based on HSB colorspace.

Is there any workaround without writing pixel-by-pixel processing code?
Thanks.

Comment: ImageMagick will switch these composite operators into HSL (or HCL, a variant of HSL that Photoshop uses, known as luma/chroma/hue model). [link: imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=21646)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the separate-and-combine approach.
Then a story has begun.

ImageMagick-6.6.9-7 has a pinpointing bug with rgb<->hsl calculation.
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS's package repository provides it... grrrr
(ImageMagick itself, fixed at r4431 and good with >= 6.6.9-9)

Then I sit down and do the math, to obtain a simple -fx expression.

colorize_hsl.fx:

```
ul = u.lightness; vl = v.lightness;
bias = (ul < .5 ? ul : 1 - ul)/(vl < .5 ? vl : 1 - vl);
(v - vl)*bias + ul
```

That is an rgb-based formula to set new lightness and preserve its hue and saturation.
To get luminize_hsl, exchange u and v.

Temporary vars (ul, vl and bias) are common in all channels,
but -fx engine might try it 3 times.
It's not enough...